# Accessing json data from wunderground API?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have this async function below that taps into a weather API and I would just like to retrieve two pieces of info from the API: Temperature in F & C. I removed the API_Key but it's free to get one on the site if necessary.

I can confirm I am receiving the json object due to my console.log(response) statement, but Im not sure how to access these data points in such heavily embedded json notation.

I guess my question is if I wanted to access say 'full' for full city name I thought I'd do something like response.observation_location.full but that doesn't work...

Help?

```
async loadWeather() {
        // let zip = this.args.zip || 97239;
        let response = await fetch(`http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json`);
        console.log(response);
        this.weather = await response.json();
        // setTimeout( () => { this.loadWeather(); }, 2000);
    }
```

Here is a partial output of the response json:

```
{
    "response": {
        "version": "0.1",
        "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
        "features": {
            "conditions": 1
        }
    },
    "current_observation": {
        "image": {
            "url": "http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
            "title": "Weather Underground",
            "link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
            "full": "San Francisco, CA",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "state": "CA",
            "state_name": "California",
            "country": "US",
            "country_iso3166": "US",
            "zip": "94102",
            "magic": "1",
            "wmo": "99999",
            "latitude": "37.77999878",
            "longitude": "-122.41999817",
            "elevation": "60.0"
        },
        "observation_location": {
            "full": "SOMA, San Francisco, California",
            "city": "SOMA, San Francisco",
            "state": "California",
            "country": "US",
            "country_iso3166": "US",
            "latitude": "37.778488",
            "longitude": "-122.408005",
            "elevation": "23 ft"
        },
```

I have tried doing `console.log(response["current_observation"])` just to access a nested data value but that doesnt seem to work as it returns undefined.

Comment: What is the response that you are receiving?

Comment: almost identical to what the example on this page shows

https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved my own issue, but for the record:

response needed to be converted to json via resonse.json()

and then I can access properties as expected

```
this.weather = await response.json();
console.log(this.weather["current_observation"]["temp_f"]);
console.log(this.weather["current_observation"]["temp_c"]);
```